# Renaming a new worksheet yields "Out of Memory" error - Why?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, out-of-memory, vba

I'm trying to make a new sheet and give it a name using the following code:

```
Sub CREATEWORKSHEETS()

    For Each PC In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
        On Error Resume Next
        PC.Refresh
    Next PC
    PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Pivot Data!$AF:$AO")

    Sheets("P&L Pivot").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("MAIN").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Sheets.Add.Name = "MAIN"
End Sub
```

But I'm always getting an "Out of Memory" error whenever it tries to create the new "MAIN" sheet. Splitting this into the following:

```
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "MAIN"
```

Suggests that the renaming operation is the culprit, but I can't figure out why. Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you get this error when you already have MAIN in the workbook?

Comment: sheets.add.name = "main" should give you an object defined error anyway.  try `set wsNew = sheets.add()` then on a new line, wsNew.name = "MAIN"`

Comment: @joseph4tw: It appears that I still get the error, even manually creating it in advance, and commenting out the delete operation for the sheet.

Comment: @scott: The following still yields the same error

    `Set wsNew = Sheets.Add()`
    `wsNew.Name = "MAIN"`

Comment: What's happening here : `Sheets("MAIN").Delete` that you need to be suppressing with the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: @Brad - That's to delete the "MAIN" sheet if it already exists. If it doesn't exist, this yields an error, since it can't be found, but we need it to continue to allow it to create the sheet in this case.

Comment: I know this will sound funny, but have you tried rebooting your computer? Do you still get the error? I'm wondering if Excel is out of memory or your computer (odd, but I figured I'd ask)

Comment: My guess is that setting a pivotcache equal to the entire columns of AF to AO is causing you to hit the excel memory limit. Try setting the pivot cache to a dynamically named range to you dont have a bunch of extra cells being held in cache

Comment: Scott: I changed the way the PivotCache is populated to find the last row of the data, and build it from that, then I moved the PivotCache generation to after the MAIN sheet is created.

I still had the problem, so I restarted Excel, which fixed it.

Feel free to post that as an answer and gain your well earned internet points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting a pivotcache equal to the entire columns of AF to AO is causing you to hit the excel memory limit. Try setting the pivot cache to a dynamically named range to you dont have a bunch of extra cells being held in cache

If you're in doubt of how much memory your pivotcache may be using try this: (copied from [this website)](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot11.html#Memory)

> You can display the memory used by a pivot cache, by using the
>   following User Defined Function. Store the function code in a
>   worksheet module. Then, on the worksheet, enter the formula:
>
> =GetMemory(A3)/1000
>
> replacing A3 with a cell in your pivot table. The result is displayed
>   in kilobytes.

```
Function GetMemory(rngPT As Range) As Long 'pivot table tutorial by
 contextures.com   Dim pt As PivotTable   Set pt = rngPT.PivotTable  
 GetMemory = ActiveWorkbook _
     .PivotCaches(pt.CacheIndex).MemoryUsed 
End Function
```